# How to set a user quota to zero?

Tags: linux, partition, quota

I know that

> Setting a quota to zero  indicates that no quota should be imposed.

So, how can I set a quota to zero, meaning the user/group is not allowed to write in that partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution in edquota manual page, your answer is the second one.

- Setting a quota to **zero** indicates that **no quota should be imposed**
- Setting a hard limit to **one** indicates that **no allocations** should be permitted.
- Setting a **soft limit** to **one** with a **hard limit** of **zero** indicates that allocations should be permitted **only on a temporary basis**

I hope this will work.

Comment: For sizes, it works. I can't do a chgrp to a "forbidden" group if the file size is non-zero. But the "no allocations" rule does not apply to inodes: I can still create one empty file or directory owned by a "forbidden" group.

Comment: @morais I haven't found any othe answers, hope you find